# Laravel Eloquent, Древовидные категории

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Всем привет, хотел бы обратиться за помощью чтобы зарефакторить отношнения в моделях в Laravel. Есть у меня таблица вида:

```
------------|------------|------------|--------------|
    City    |  Category  |Subcategory |   Company    |
------------|------------|------------|--------------|
     id     |     id     |    id      |     id       |
            |   city_id  |category_id |subcategory_id|
    name    |    name    |    name    |    name      |
------------|------------|------------|--------------|
```

**City.php**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
}
```

**Subcategory.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
}
```

В общем проблема в том что городов много а категории могут быть одни и те же для всех городов, в моём случае же категории повторяются для каждого города, вчера весь день над этим думал, пробовал все возможные отношения с Laravel и никак не смог продумать логику. 
Пример: 
Если я добавляю например новый города и после этого захочу к нему категории прикрепить и каждый раз получается что я создаю новую и дублирующую категории именно для 1 города...
Очень надеюсь на помощь...Как правильно нужно такое сделать!?

> *Логика такая:* **У нас есть города у которых много компаний и эти компании поделены на категории и подкатегории.**
>   Как на zoon.ru сделано. Выбираешь город, появляется категории и внизу подкатегории.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема сейчас в том что у вас не совсем верное понятие отношений 1 ко многим и многие ко многим. Город по факту у вас один, а компаний в городе много! Компания у вас одна, а категорий у нее много ....Или есть такие категории (например Бытовая техника) в одном городе, которые принадлежат разным компаниям (и вот в ней может быть 10 компаний которые предоставляют бытовую технику)  ? Если так, то вы неверно описываете вашу логику

Comment: @Orange_shadow У категорий есть подкатегории а компании находятся в подкатегориях уже. Категорий у компаний не много, скажем компания "ООО Пример" находиться в городе Москва в категории "Foo" и подкатегории "Bar". Только тут и нигде больше. В Пензе в категории "Foo" и подкатегории "Bar" нету этой компании. Надеюсь правильно объяснил. Я просто нехочу чтобы одни и те же категори и подкатегории повторялись для каждого добавленного города.

Comment: Ну значит у тебя должны быть отельные таблицы каторые делают связь city_category, category_company, а подкатегории вообще можно реализовать как категория у которой есть parent_id, если конечно одна подкатегория не имеет двух родителей, тогда у тебя будет все в нормализованном виде

Comment: @Orange_shadow Думаю это и есть ответ, можете в более развернутом виде ответить, чтобы выбрать ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем проблема? Компания имеет один город, одну категорию и, возможно, несколько подкатегорий.

Company:

```
public function city() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Model\City::class);
}


public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Model\Category::class);
}

public function SubCategory() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Model\SubCategory::class);
}
```

Город, в свою очередь, имеет много компаний.

City:

```
public function company() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Model\Company::class);
}
```

Ну, категории и подкатегории, я думаю, в поянении не нуждаются.

Comment: Если я захочу вывести компании одного города делаю так: `$city->company;` А если захочу вывести `категории` и внизу `под-категории` и при нажатии на `под-категории` вывести именно `компании` выбранного **города**, то как это сделать?

Comment: Допустим в `php artisan tinker` я делаю следующее  
**Москва:** `App\City::find(1)->categories->first()->subcategories->first()->companies;` 
**Питер:** `App\City::find(2)->categories->first()->subcategories->first()->companies;` 
Я получаю одни и те же компании.

Comment: Откуда у города категории? Компании нужно выбирать из категорий и фильтровать по городу при помощи ::whereHas('city_id', function ($query) use ($city_id) {
   $query->where('city_id', '=', $city_id);
  })

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать 2 дополнительные таблицы:

1) city_category c составным ключом: {city_id,category_id},
что позволит нам указывать только те категории, которые есть в данном городе

2) category_company с ключом: {category_id,company_id}, позволит связывать несколько компаний с несколькими категориями

Так же можно упразднить таблицу Subcategory, добавив в таблице Category  поле parent_id, так как по факту это одна и та же сущность, но это только в том случае если у вас одна категория не может иметь несколько родителей.

Comment: Смотрите, скажем у нас много городов и каждого города компании свои. Если мы сделаем так как Вы описали, получается 2 `belongsToMany`. Получиться 1 город можно связать с несколькими категориями также 1 категорию с несколькими компаниями, но тогда у нас во всех городах получаться одни и те же города. А на счет parent_id не очень понял, можете пример привести, Это `belongsTo` будет?

Comment: @pwnz22 Не понял вот эту фразу: "но тогда у нас во всех городах получаться одни и те же города", Ну смотри, какая разница у тебя отдельная таблица с надписью category_id и с теми же полями или просто будет таблица categories c полями {id, title,description, parent_id}, да связь будет belongsTo

Comment: category_company с ключом: {category_id,company_id} - Если мы связываем компании с категориями то у нас получиться одни и те же компании во всех категориях, так как категории связаны с городами то компании будут одни и те же во всех городах

Comment: @pwnz22 ну тогда тебе нужна еще одна таблица :)  comany_city, тогда будешь обрезать в выборке только те компании, которые есть в данном городе в данной категории

Comment: @pwnz22 можно конечно сделать тройной составной ключ, но я чет не уверен, что это не моветон :) да и реализация поведения тут станет наверное чуточку сложнее

Comment: @pwnz22 Реализация тройной связи, есть [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543221/how-to-query-pivot-table-with-multiple-foreign-keys-laravel-5-eloquent)

Comment: Идея на счет parent_id очень помогла, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------------|
    City    |city_category|  Category  |Subcategory |   Company    |
------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------------|
     id     |   city_id   |     id     |    id      |     id       |
            |             |            |category_id |subcategory_id|
    name    | category_id |    name    |    name    |    name      |
------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------------|
```

Добавте табличку и метод belongsToMany в модели

Comment: Это не подойдет. Так как несколько городов не могут иметь одни и те же компании. Если мы сделаем только один belongsToMany с категориями получиться что далее в подкатегориях будут те же категории что и во всех городах ну и компании те же...У нас в разных городах разные компании.

Comment: По аналогу category_company добавить..